# How to read available text (not ending with new line) from TCP socket using BufferedReader

Tags: android, multithreading, sockets, tcp

I'm communication with a server through a tcp socket connection, i'm able to read lines that ends with `\n` fine, however when the line is not terminated (ends in `\n`) i'm not able to read it. I tried the following but it didn't work and caused my app to freeze at startup:

```
private Socket socket;
private BufferedReader input;
public boolean isConnected;

@Override
public void onCreate()
{
    try
    {
        socket = new Socket ("server.ip.add.ress", 23456);
        input = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (socket.getInputStream());
        handshake();
        isConnected = true;
    }
    catch // Handle IOException and UnknownHostException
}

// custom runnable to read availabe input from the server
private class MyRunnable implements Runnable
{
    private volativle String value;
    public String getValue()
    {
        return value;
    }
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        int count;
        char[] buffer = new char[10]; // expected message 'username: '
        try
        {
            count = input.read (buffer, 0, 10);
            if (count > 0) value = new String (buffer);
        }
        catch // IOException
    }
}

// when connection is established with server expect 'username: ' from
// the server and send the user name back to it
public void handshake()
{
    MyRunnable runnable = new MyRunnable();
    try
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread (runnable);
        thread.start();
        thread.join();
        String greeting = runnable.getValue();
        if (greeting.equals ("username: ")) // Send username back
    }
    catch // InterruptedException
}
```

why is it hanging? and how can i read a non terminated line?

### Edit:

**To clarify:**  The server sends the greeting message `username:`  immediately after the connection is established with a client, the client wait for the greeting and send back it's username when received (that's what `handshake()` does), if no handshake the client disconnects otherwise it start listening for incoming messages. Because i need to know if handshake is complete before starting the listener i had to use `Thread.join()`.

**The problem:** Thanks for the comments and answers below, it turned out that `BufferedReader.read()` blocks the thread and waits until something is sent from the server and if nothing is being sent it causes the app to hang, Therefor *there's no way to find out if the line has ended*.

**The solution:** *In my specific situation* i just wanted to know if a specific message is sent "username: " so i used `read (buffer, 0, 10)` to read exactly 10 characters (the length of "username: "), and because it blocks if nothing is sent i used `Thread.join (1000)` which waits only one second and then if nothing received i disconnect the client.

Comment: This code can only block if nothing is sent at all. `Thread.start()` followed by `Thread.join()` is pointless. `new String(buffer)` should be `new String(buffer, 0, count);`

Comment: how can i check if there is a message sent from server or not?

Comment: You *are* checking. It isn't.

Comment: @EJP you're right the server is not sending anything. But why is `read()` blocking? can it not just return if nothing is available?

Comment: No. See the Javdoc. It blocks until at least one character has been transferred, or end of stream or an exception occurs.

Answer (score 1):

#### Why is it hanging?

This is what it is suppose to be. It will block the thread if no data is available to read. This is also why you want to put it in a background thread.

#### Can it not just return if nothing is available?

What you are looking for is [ready()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/BufferedReader.html#ready()), which will tell you whether there is available data or not.

> Indicates whether this reader is ready to be read without blocking.
>   **Returns**
>   true if this reader will not block when read is called, false if unknown or blocking will occur.

But you should be very careful when using this function. Because networking is a lot about timing. The fact that you don't have any data to read at this second doesn't necessary mean that it won't be any data in the next second.

So a better design of the server should be more or less as the following:

- If the username is found, return the username
- If the username is not found, return an error message to let the client side know that the username is not found

Comment: `ready()` didn't work because as you said there's a timing issue, the socket is not ready when `ready()` is called, it takes a fracture of second for the message to be received.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for the thread.  Your goal is to wait until you've read what you've been waiting for.  Why not just let read() perform the wait for you?

What you're struggling with is the classic problem of TCP communication: "when do I know that I've got everything the server sent?"

In your case, you're expecting to read bytes until the collection of bytes **ends with** "username: ".  So, change your algorithm to perform **1 byte** reads (filling a buffer as you go) until that buffer ends with "username: ".

You can make a more complicated algorithm -- which would be more efficient -- that would attempt to read multiple bytes at a time and append them to a buffer -- performing your check each time.  But either strategy is logically equivalent.

I also recommend just using the InputStreamReader.  It has various read() methods.  I am a bit suspicious about the BufferedInputReader, especially when dealing with data that isn't newline terminated.  I'm probably just paranoid.  I've just never used it when writing TCP client/server programs, so I'm not sure.

Comment: Your fears are unfounded.